# countif changes with autofilter for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA project and I want it to count the number of cells within a range that matches a particular criteria.

So are two columns and the countif would count the value if two requirements are fulfilled. 
In addition, I have added autofilter to range, therefore the count will change when you filter the columns (For instance the value would change if i select certain classroom rather than all classroom)

```
        dim i as integer
    dim rcell as integer
    lastrow = Activesheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Col_Dessert =5
Col_Snack =6

i=0

    with Worksheets("JIS")
For rcell = 1 to lastrow
If range(cells(rcell,Col_Dessert).value="L" ) And range(cells(rcell,Col_Dessert).value="WESTERN" ) then
i=i+1

end if
next rcell
end with
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please copy/paste your code instead of re-typing it here. Then also format and indent it correctly for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this **does** need to be in VBA - and I can think of various situations where it would - then you can use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get *only* the Cells that are Visible - e.g.

```
Dim Col_Dessert As Long, Col_Snack As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim rowCheck As Range, wsCheck As Worksheet

Col_Dessert = 5
Col_Snack = 6

i = 0
Set wsCheck = Worksheets("JIS")
For Each rowCheck In Intersect(wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1), wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Cells
    If wsCheck.Cells(rowCheck.Row, Col_Dessert).Value = "L" And wsCheck.Cells(rowCheck.Row, Col_Dessert).Value = "WESTERN" Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next rowCheck

Set wsCheck = Nothing
```

However, if you are trying to create User Defined Function to do this in the Worksheet, consider a `SUMPRODUCT` with `SUBTOTAL(103` (i.e. `COUNTA` while ignoring hidden rows) instead.  Basic form:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ConditionRange1="Value1")*--(ConditionRange2="Value2")*--SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($A$1,ROW(ConditionRange1)-1,0)))
```

Adapted for you, to match `"L"` in Column E and `"WESTERN"` in Column F:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$1:$E$100="L")*--($F$1:$F$100="WESTERN")*--SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($A$1,ROW($A$1:$A$100)-1,0)))
```

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal, Thanks for helping me, however the count does not adjust according to the autofilter. So when i filter the rows, the count should reflect the change. For instance when i deselect Class A in the autofilter, the count should change

Comment: @nikhilsharma Which of the options are you using?  If you're using a UDF, you may need `Application.Volatile` at the start to make it recalculate when the workbook changes

Comment: ,yes its a UDF,

Comment: @nikhilsharma Read [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Volatile)

Comment: let me give it a try. I posted my code based on your suggestions in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim wsCheck As Worksheet

i = 0
Set wsCheck = Worksheets("JIS")
For Each r In Intersect(wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(5), wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Cells
    If wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Starter).Value = "S" And wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Dessert).Value = "WESTERN" Then
        i = i + 1
        wsCheck.Range("A5") = "S:" & " " & i
    End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Long 
Dim r As Range
 Dim wsCheck As Worksheet 
i = 0 
Set wsCheck = Worksheets("JIS")
 wsCheck.Application.Volatile (True) 
For Each r In Intersect(wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(Col_Western), wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Cells
If wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Starter).Value = "S" And wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Dessert).Value = "WESTERN" Then i = i + 1 wsCheck.Range("A5") = "S:" & " " & i 
End If 
Next r 
Set wsCheck = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA. Use Excel smart formulas.

> `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(EDIManifestsAll[UniqueContainer],
>   ROW(EDIManifestsAll[UniqueContainer])-ROW(EDIManifestsAll[UniqueContainer]),0,1)),
>   --(EDIManifestsAll[UniqueContainer]="Y"))`

Where:

- `EDIManifestsAll` = your table reference or name
- `UniqueContainer` = your filtered column heading
- "Y" = any arbitrary value that you want to `COUNTIF()`

ps: my answer is based on your title *"countif changes with autofilter ..."*. If you're trying to resolve in VBA specifically, then all other answers should do it.